# Share text and image with android intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

That is my code java

```
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My App name and some text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "a link");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,getImageUri(context,mBitmap));
    intent.setType("image/*,text/plain");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I want to share  image and  text. This code  works on WhatsApp, Twitter, Gmail , etc .. but it does not work on Facebook

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I assume that you are using `ACTION_SEND`, in which case there are two clear problems. First, `setType()` does not take a comma-delimited list. Second, `ACTION_SEND` supports *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both. Both of these points are covered in [the `ACTION_SEND` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). Given your code, change it to `intent.setType("image/*");` and see if that helps. If it does not, please edit your question to explain what "does not work on Facebook" means and post what `getImageUri()` is returning.

Comment: since android 4.3 setType() can take comma-delimited list and also ACTION_SEND supports EXTRA_TEXT and EXTRA_STREAM.         I says my code works for twitter, whatsapp and gmail

Comment: "since android 4.3 setType() can take comma-delimited list" -- that is [not documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)). "ACTION_SEND supports EXTRA_TEXT and EXTRA_STREAM" -- not at the same time. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), "get*Extra can have **either** a EXTRA_TEXT **or** EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in EXTRA_STREAM"

Comment: Apps *can* elect to try to honor both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`. But they do not *have* to, because the documentation says they do not have to. Do not expect all apps to support both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share the Image and text on Facebook without using Facebook SDK then you have to create the bitmap of your image plus text and then you can share that bitmap on facebook.

Download the source code from here ([Share image and text on facebook using intent in android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/share-image-and-text-on-facebook-using-intent-in-android/))

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_drawable"
        android:hint="Enter your text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#979797" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rl_main"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_share">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:maxLines="5"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_share"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#F38D0A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText et_text;
    ImageView iv_image;
    TextView tv_share,tv_text;
    RelativeLayout rl_main;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        et_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        tv_share = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_share);
        rl_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        tv_text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

        File dir = new File("/sdcard/Testing/");
        try {
            if (dir.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory is not created");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv_share.setOnClickListener(this);

        et_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tv_text.setText(et_text.getText().toString());

            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tv_share:
                Bitmap bitmap1 = loadBitmapFromView(rl_main, rl_main.getWidth(), rl_main.getHeight());
                saveBitmap(bitmap1);
                String str_screenshot = "/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg";

                fn_share(str_screenshot);
                break;
        }

    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagePath = new File("/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }

    public void fn_share(String path) {

        File file = new File("/mnt/" + path);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));


    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can share int value of an image as R.drawable.image and get it with getResources.getDrawable(int)